# How-To Use Multiple Android Studio Templates in One Project?

Tags: templates, merge, project, android-studio

Android Studio is so new that the documentation leaves some information out. I have been trying to use more than one of the templates provided in a single project. Specifically, I'd like to use the "Login" template along with the "Master-Detail" template in the same project.

I'd even be happy to create two projects and merge the activities created, but it was not successful so far.

Answer (score 0):

Go to res → layout folder (right click) → New → Activity → find your desired layout